# How to save and display a photo that an app made

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

This is a pretty big question, I tried a lot to do it, but I just didn't get it and im failing pretty hard. So I made an application with an menu with 2buttons. If you click the button "addpic" it goes to the class "FotoMaker" and you can make a picture there if you click the button "make_pic". Now I want to save this picture if a user presses the button "save_pic". Then after when you click on "watch_your_picture" in the MenuScreen.java it should call the watch_pic.xml which is getting called in the ShowPhoto.java file. And you should see the photo(s) in here. This is what I get already:

PhotoMaker.java:

```
package com.example.random;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class FotoMaker extends Activity 
    {
    ImageView iv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addpic);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {


            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if(requestCode == 0)
            {
                Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
            }
        }

    }
```

ShowPhoto.java:

```
package com.example.random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ShowPhoto extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.watch_pic);


}
}
```

addpic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="make a picture here"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/make_pic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/save_pic" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

watch_pic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="imageViewer1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">random</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="watch_your_picture">watch your picture here</string>
    <string name="nothing_here_yet">will add something here later</string>
    <string name="addpic">make picture here</string>
    <string name="verlaat_app">Verlaat de app</string>
    <string name="make_pic">make picture</string>
    <string name="save_pic">SAVE</string>
    <string name="imageView1">test is a generic contect</string>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hello you can recover the uri of image in the onActivityResult and when you click to watch_your_picture you send the Uri of the picture to the next activity you can modify your code as above :

`

```
    package com.example.random; 




    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.contect.ContectValues;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;


    public class FotoMaker extends Activity 
        { 
        ImageView iv;
        Uri uriOfPicture;


        @Override 
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.addpic);

            iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            { 


                @Override 
                public void onClick (View v){
                    takeImageFromCamera();

                } 
            }); 
            } 
            @Override 
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            { 
                if(requestCode == 0)
                { 
                    Bitmap image=createBitmapFromURI(uriOfPicture);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(image);
                } 
            } 
    @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            if (currImageURI != null) {
                outState.putString("cameraImageUri", uriOfPicture.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
                uriOfPicture = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
            }
        }
    /*********************************** method to take URI of the picture *******************/
    public void takeImageFromCamera(){
            String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                    "Image captured by camera");

            uriOfPicture = getContentResolver()
                    .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            values);  
            Log.i("uri",currImageURI.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriOfPicture);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    0);


        }

public Bitmap createBitmapFromURI(Uri uri) {

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getApplicationContext()
                        .getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (bitmap != null)
/*********dimention**********************/
                return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }


        }
```

`

Comment: Okay added this part to the code, but I got 3 errors, all of the "currImageURI". It tells me: "currImageURI cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Ah yes you just change currImageURI by uriOfPicture

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpfull awnser. I have one more question: Lets saw I also put a TextBox called "textbox" in my "addpic" layout. What do I change in the code to store the text from the textbox with the picture?

Comment: I do not know if I understand your question, but you can retrieve the contents of textBox with getText () by this way you can use as you want

Comment: Okay, well I got that part now. But I dont really get it how you display the picture you just made. The ShowPhoto.java file

Comment: oki,and me I got to part now! I shoud modify this code you find it soon as possible good luck

Comment: BTW there is an error in ur code, when I made a photo, the app crashes, I will watch and upload the logcat. It gives the error outofmemory

Comment: this error is caused by the big dimension of the image so you shoud get bitmap picture by using URI and replace setImageUri by setImageBitmap chek the code I modify it

Comment: Well, I can only make 1 photo now, if I make a second one, the app shuts down. I want to make muliple photos in my layout. And save them all, and show them finally in ShowPhoto.java